# Devexpress XtraList make child nodes parent nodes?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtratreelist

I have a XtraTreeList with several parent nodes, each parent node have several child nodes appended to them.

What i want to extract all child nodes from their parent, remove the parent nodes, then bind all these child nodes as parent. In short i want to remove the parent nodes and make all the child as parent nodes.

I tried several ways like using the TreeList.MoveNode() but that didn't work for me.

Edit:

I have deleted my previous answer and added new one which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The work around i did was that i have selected all the nodes from the code, and called the DeleteSelectedNodes(), here is the code:

```
            List<int> nodeIdsToMove = new List<int>();
        List<int> nodeIdsToRemove = new List<int>();

        if (comboBox_GroupBy.SelectedItem.ToString() == "None")
        {
            /* Parent nodes */
            foreach(TreeListNode parentNode in treeList_Links.Nodes)
            {
                nodeIdsToRemove.Add(parentNode.Id);
                if (parentNode.HasChildren)
                {
                    /* Child nodes */
                    foreach (TreeListNode childNode in parentNode.Nodes)
                        nodeIdsToMove.Add(childNode.Id);
                }
            }

            MoveNodes(nodeIdsToMove);
            RemoveNode(nodeIdsToRemove);
```

And here is the MoveNode and RemoveNode implemention:

```
        private void MoveNodes(List<int> nodeIdsToMove)
    {
        foreach (int nodeId in nodeIdsToMove)
            treeList_Links.MoveNode(treeList_Links.FindNodeByID(nodeId), null);
    }
```

private void RemoveNode(List nodeIdsToRemove)
        {
            /* Enalbe multiselect */
            treeList_Links.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = true;

```
        /* Get nodes to select */
        ArrayList nodesToSelect = new ArrayList();
        foreach (int nodeId in nodeIdsToRemove)
            nodesToSelect.Add(treeList_Links.FindNodeByID(nodeId));

        /* Select nodes */
        treeList_Links.Selection.Set(nodesToSelect);

        /* Delete selected nodes */
        treeList_Links.DeleteSelectedNodes();

        /* Disable multiselect */
        treeList_Links.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = false;
    }
```